# Can not print data in php from table mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I can not display data from the table, please  Help! 
when I run out this error:
Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.com\index.php on line 3

```html
<?php include ("blocks/bd.php");
$result = $db->query("SELECT title,id,meta_d,meta_k,text,page FROM 'settings'");
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)

{
$myrow = mysqli_fetch_array($result); 
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title><?php echo $myrow["title"]; ?></title>//so here I need to show data from table
```

Comment: You need to replace `'settings'` by `settings`

Comment: @Mr. Developer thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't to put single qoutes in the query. Please change following

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT title,id,meta_d,meta_k,text,page FROM 'settings'");
```

to

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT title,id,meta_d,meta_k,text,page FROM `settings`");
```